# Jenkins to run groovy cmd

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to run the following cmd

```
groovy http://frankencover.it/with -source-dir MyProject/Classes -required-coverage 85
```

from a Jenkins server as a bash script. I get the following error:

```
/var/folders/mk/jw29t1bj6tg1tymgysyw83b4k_7h97/T/hudson3694832164452107476.sh: line 2: groovy: command not found
```

Is there a way I can let Jenkins run a groovy command? When I run the command from the terminal, it totally works fine. I do have groovy installed

Comment: Have you set groovy location in jenkins? you have groovy plugin to run groovy scripts

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Configure the Groovy path in configure system.

Then you can use Groovy plugin to execute grrovy scripts

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin